# Как обновить UserDetails в ходе сессии?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, сессия, spring-security

Для хранения сессий я использую Spring Session и Redis, а для безопасности Spring Security и собственные имплементации `UserDetailsService` и `UserDetails`.

Вот сервис:

```
@Override
protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return email -> {
        User user = service.getByEmail(email.toLowerCase());
        return new AuthorizedUser(user, getProfileTo(user));
    };
}
```

Вот моя имплементация `UserDetails`:

```
@Getter
@ToString
public class AuthorizedUser extends org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User {

    private final ProfileTo profile;

    public AuthorizedUser(User user, ProfileTo profile) {
        // некоторая логика
    }

    public void updateTelNum(String telNum) {
        profile.setTelNum(telNum);
    }
}
```

Суть в чём. Пользователь может захотеть обновить свой номер телефона. Поэтому я сделал такой эндпоинт:

```
@PutMapping(value = "/tel-num", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void updateTelNum(@RequestBody TelNumTo telNum, @AuthenticationPrincipal AuthorizedUser user) {
    service.updateTelNum(telNum.getTelNum(), user.getProfile().id());
}
```

Он работает приемлимо. Значение в базе данных действительно обновляется. Проблема следующая: объект `AuthorizedUser`, который относится к пользователю, не обновляется, пока сессия не будет сброшена. В принципе, я понимаю механизм этого: `AuthorizedUser` вытаскивается из базы данных единожды при аутентификации и сохраняется в SecurityContext. Ну и сколько ты потом данные в базе данных не меняй, данные в `AuthorizedUser` останутся прежними.

Я хочу делать данные актуальными. Я специально сделал вот такой метод в `AuthorizedUser`:

```
public void updateTelNum(String telNum) {
    profile.setTelNum(telNum);
}
```

но это не работает. Вот что я делал в эндпоинте:

```
@PutMapping(value = "/tel-num", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void updateTelNum(@RequestBody TelNumTo telNum, @AuthenticationPrincipal AuthorizedUser user) {
    service.updateTelNum(telNum.getTelNum(), user.getProfile().id());
    SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    Authentication auth = context.getAuthentication();
    AuthorizedUser authUser = (AuthorizedUser) auth.getPrincipal();
    authUser.updateAdvancedInfo(telNum.getTelNum());
}
```

Никакого эффекта. Вероятно, проблема именно в том, что я храню сессию в Redis. Не знаю. Как я могу обновить данные в `AuthorizedUser`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему, изучив эти две ссылки: [раз](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33990321/14614707), [два](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/398).

Сделал вот так:

```
@PutMapping(value = "/{id}/tel-num", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void updateTelNum(@Valid @RequestBody TelNumTo telNum,
                         @AuthenticationPrincipal AuthorizedUser user) {
    service.updateTelNum(telNum.getTelNum(), user.getProfile().id());

    user.setAdvancedInfo(telNum.getTelNum());
    Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, user.getAuthorities());
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
    RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().setAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT", auth, RequestAttributes.SCOPE_SESSION);
}
```

То есть мы здесь ещё и к Redis обращаемся. Любопытно, что если убрать эту строку: `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth)` *(что я сразу и сделал)*, то упадёт интересная ошибка:

> SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT did not contain a SecurityContext but
> contained: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=...]'; are
> you improperly modifying the HttpSession directly (you should always
> use SecurityContextHolder) or using the HttpSession attribute reserved
> for this class?

Мой английский довольно плох, но я понял, что ругается Spring на то, что SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT не содержит SecurityContext. Я на самом деле не понимаю почему так, ведь в той строке, которую я убрал, контекст никуда не устанавливается. Мы просто изменяем его содержимое. Но, видимо, это как-то влияет. Буду признателен, если кто-то объяснит, почему. Но, если строку не убирать, это работает.